# Using UserDefaults in sceneWillResignActive method in SceneDelegate.swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making a notes app which would save user default data when the app is in background state or when the app has just moved to the background.

This is the code from ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let item = defaults.string(forKey: "Notes") {
            textField.text = item
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code from SceneDelegate.swift

```
import UIKit
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
    var window: UIWindow?
    let vc = ViewController()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    }
    func sceneDidDisconnect(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
    func sceneDidBecomeActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
    func sceneWillResignActive(_ scene: UIScene) {
        print("scene will resign active")
        defaults.set(vc.textField.text!, forKey: "Notes") /*error*/
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
    func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
    }
}
```

I have already implemented the same on a `@IBAction button` and it did work fine. But when I am saving the defaults data in `sceneWillResignActive()` method it shows me this error

> /* error - Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value */

How do I save **UserDefault** data in **sceneWillResignActive()** method or any other scene method?

Comment: The problem is that the line `let vc = ViewController()` has _absolutely nothing_ to do with the view controller that's in your interface. http://www.programmingios.net/dont-make-a-new-instance-by-mistake/

Comment: If this is so, how am I going to save the UserDefaults while the sceneWillResignActive() method is being activated?

Comment: Oh, well, you would do that from _inside_ the ViewController. It can register for the notification for when the scene will resign. And since you are inside the view controller, the `textField` belongs to you, it is `self.textField`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `UIWindowSceneDelegate` all I have to do is use `UITextViewDelegate` **Protocol**.
There was no need to change any piece of code in ***SceneDelegate.swift***, as no instance of `Scenes` was used entirely.
There was a need to save the instance as soon as the *textViewField* did finish editing.

> ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textView.delegate = self
    textView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
    
   
    if let item = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "Notes") {
        textView.text! = item
    }

}

func textViewDidChange(_ textView: UITextView) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(textView.text!, forKey: "Notes")
   }  
}
```

Read the Apple documentation of UITextViewDelegate [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextviewdelegate).

You can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzWBT6lIB3A&t=558s) video for reference.
Thank You!!